# Setting bundle parameter in security.yml in Symfony2

Tags: dependency-injection, symfony

I'm facing issues : in my security.yml I try to inject a parameter class as follow :

security:
    acl:
        connection: default

```
encoders:
    %my_ubercoolbundle.user_class%
        algorithm: sha512

providers:
    main:
        entity: { class: %my_ubercoolbundle.user_class%, property: username }
```

and of course this parameter is handled in my bundle Configuration and Extension classes :

```
->children()
    ->scalarNode('user_class')->defaultValue('My/UbercoolBundle/Entity/User')->end()
->end()
```

and

```
$container->setParameter('my_ubercool.user_class', $config['user_class']);
```

But when sf2 compiles my project, it tells me

```
ParameterNotFoundException: You have requested a non-existent parameter "my_ubercool.user_class".
```

Any idea of why it does this to me?
Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved : It's not possible in SF2 to inject datas from a bundle to the app configuration.

Comment: Since I'm facing the very same issue, I'll assume that you made a typo when obfuscating your vendor name (you meant `my_ubercool` instead of `my_ubercoolbundle`).


Two years later, is it still impossible to inject data from bundle to app configuration?

Comment: Up, is it still impossible ? I can add bundles to `assetic:bundle` from bundle extension (https://github.com/alcalyn/elc/blob/master/src/EL/CoreBundle/DependencyInjection/CoreExtension.php#L29-L31), but I cannot append a `doctrine.orm.mapping` since I no longer use `auto_mapping` to put entities outside the bundle

Comment: I think it was impossible in 2012 with the old symfony2 version I used. Didn't do some SF2 since ages, I have to refresh my knowledge but I won't be surprised that's now possible in the latest SF2 versons!